# running python program on startup in tty4

Tags: ubuntu, autorun

I want to setup program that will automaticly run in tty4 (if its possible, if not then can be run in any other tty) on system start.
My python script is at /home/vakus/main.py
I have no GUI, only consoles.
I couldn't find anything that could solve my problem

Sorry for my English.

Comment: which version of ubuntu? `lsb_release -r`

Comment: ubuntu version 15.04

Comment: are you using systemd or upstart? if `systemctl status` says lots of stuff, it's systemd. if `ps alx|grep upstart` lists several processes it's upstart.

Comment: it doesnt have `ps alx|grep upstart`, but it have much times word `systemd`. If this might help I using virtualbox for ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have an ubuntu with **systemd**, but I do have a fedora 20 with it, so I'm
assuming they are similar. You may need to change filenames a bit.

First create a systemd service file. You should find lots of such files in `/lib/systemd/system/` or similar.

```
sudo bash <<\!eof
cat > /lib/systemd/system/mystuff.service <<\!
[Unit]
Description=Run my stuff from systemd
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/vakus/main.py <>/dev/tty4
Restart=no
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
!
!eof
```

I've used `<>` to make the shell open /dev/tty4 for stdin and stdout.
Check that there is no **getty** running on tty4 and stop and disable it if there is.

```
systemctl status getty@tty4.service
sudo systemctl stop getty@tty4.service
sudo systemctl disable getty@tty4.service
```

Then enable your service to be started on boot, and make systemd take notice of it now:

```
sudo systemctl enable mystuff.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Activate the service now to see if it works, and check the status:

```
sudo systemctl start mystuff.service
systemctl status mystuff.service
```